# Issue with Sidebar positioning

Tags: html, css, templates

I have created my first template but my sidebar is not working as expected. Please take a look at this: http://neo4evr.com/templates/torque/

As you can see, the sidebar has gone down to the footer position and not at the side of `#content div`, as I wanted. Can anyone help me to bring it beside the `content div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly clear your `#container` div and float your content to the left to fix your issue. Try this:

```
#container:after {
    clear: both;
}
#container:before, #container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    zoom:1; /* ie fix */
}

#content {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That has fixed the issue... :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy. Just add `display: inline-block` to the `div#content`. The sidebar will then goes up and sits next to the `div#content`. One thing you might notice though, the sidebar might be a little bit higher than the content. If you want to take it down a little bit just so that it aligns with the content, just add the same amount of padding to the top of the sidebar like the one with the content. Which in this case, it's `20px`.